# Android Image downloaders / cache managers

Tags: android, caching

Masters, I'm developing a Google plus like application in android. Which will render feeds from server. I am using a custom listview and populating it. Between, I have images to display in each list item.

I am using the below code to download the image and put in on views.

I got it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/android/imagedownloader/ImageDownloader.java?r=3)., And many other places I've seen the same code used.

**The Problem here is**

1. Caching is not happening. I Logged the calls and found that , each time the image is getting downloaded newly.
2. I need a solution where, I need to store some images, when the request url comes, it should check with existing cache and provide image. Without making it download from web again.

**Could anyone suggest me any good libraries to do the same, OR any easy fix for the below code.**

Please note, I am not an expert :)

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


/**
 * This helper class download images from the Internet and binds those with the provided ImageView.
 *
 * <p>It requires the INTERNET permission, which should be added to your application's manifest
 * file.</p>
 *
 * A local cache of downloaded images is maintained internally to improve performance.
 */
public class ImageDownloader {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ImageDownloader";

    public enum Mode { NO_ASYNC_TASK, NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE, CORRECT }
    private Mode mode = Mode.NO_ASYNC_TASK;

    /**
     * Download the specified image from the Internet and binds it to the provided ImageView. The
     * binding is immediate if the image is found in the cache and will be done asynchronously
     * otherwise. A null bitmap will be associated to the ImageView if an error occurs.
     *
     * @param url The URL of the image to download.
     * @param imageView The ImageView to bind the downloaded image to.
     */
    public void download(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        resetPurgeTimer();
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromCache(url);

        if (bitmap == null) {
            forceDownload(url, imageView);
        } else {
            cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Same as download but the image is always downloaded and the cache is not used.
     * Kept private at the moment as its interest is not clear.
       private void forceDownload(String url, ImageView view) {
          forceDownload(url, view, null);
       }
     */

    /**
     * Same as download but the image is always downloaded and the cache is not used.
     * Kept private at the moment as its interest is not clear.
     */
    private void forceDownload(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        // State sanity: url is guaranteed to never be null in DownloadedDrawable and cache keys.
        if (url == null) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
            return;
        }

        if (cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView)) {
            switch (mode) {
                case NO_ASYNC_TASK:
                    Bitmap bitmap = downloadBitmap(url);
                    addBitmapToCache(url, bitmap);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    break;

                case NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE:
                    imageView.setMinimumHeight(156);
                    BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                    task.execute(url);
                    break;

                case CORRECT:
                    task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                    DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = new DownloadedDrawable(task);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(downloadedDrawable);
                    imageView.setMinimumHeight(156);
                    task.execute(url);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the current download has been canceled or if there was no download in
     * progress on this image view.
     * Returns false if the download in progress deals with the same url. The download is not
     * stopped in that case.
     */
    private static boolean cancelPotentialDownload(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);

        if (bitmapDownloaderTask != null) {
            String bitmapUrl = bitmapDownloaderTask.url;
            if ((bitmapUrl == null) || (!bitmapUrl.equals(url))) {
                bitmapDownloaderTask.cancel(true);
            } else {
                // The same URL is already being downloaded.
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param imageView Any imageView
     * @return Retrieve the currently active download task (if any) associated with this imageView.
     * null if there is no such task.
     */
    private static BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        if (imageView != null) {
            Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
            if (drawable instanceof DownloadedDrawable) {
                DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = (DownloadedDrawable)drawable;
                return downloadedDrawable.getBitmapDownloaderTask();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 4 * 1024;

        // AndroidHttpClient is not allowed to be used from the main thread
        final HttpClient client = (mode == Mode.NO_ASYNC_TASK) ? new DefaultHttpClient() :
            AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode +
                        " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                return null;
            }

            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(inputStream));
                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "I/O error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Incorrect URL: " + url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e);
        } finally {
            if ((client instanceof AndroidHttpClient)) {
                ((AndroidHttpClient) client).close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * A patched InputSteam that tries harder to fully read the input stream.
     */
    static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
        public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
            super(inputStream);
        }

        @Override
        public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
            long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
            while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
                long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n-totalBytesSkipped);
                if (bytesSkipped == 0L) break;
                totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
            }
            return totalBytesSkipped;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The actual AsyncTask that will asynchronously download the image.
     */
    class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private String url;
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        /**
         * Actual download method.
         */
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            url = params[0];
            return downloadBitmap(url);
        }

        /**
         * Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }

            addBitmapToCache(url, bitmap);

            if (imageViewReference != null) {
                ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                // Change bitmap only if this process is still associated with it
                // Or if we don't use any bitmap to task association (NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE mode)
                if ((this == bitmapDownloaderTask) || (mode != Mode.CORRECT)) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * A fake Drawable that will be attached to the imageView while the download is in progress.
     *
     * <p>Contains a reference to the actual download task, so that a download task can be stopped
     * if a new binding is required, and makes sure that only the last started download process can
     * bind its result, independently of the download finish order.</p>
     */
    static class DownloadedDrawable extends ColorDrawable {
        private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

        public DownloadedDrawable(BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask) {
            super(Color.BLACK);
            bitmapDownloaderTaskReference =
                new WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask>(bitmapDownloaderTask);
        }

        public BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask() {
            return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
        }
    }

    public void setMode(Mode mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
        clearCache();
    }


    /*
     * Cache-related fields and methods.
     * 
     * We use a hard and a soft cache. A soft reference cache is too aggressively cleared by the
     * Garbage Collector.
     */

    private static final int HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY = 10;
    private static final int DELAY_BEFORE_PURGE = 10 * 1000; // in milliseconds

    // Hard cache, with a fixed maximum capacity and a life duration
    private final HashMap<String, Bitmap> sHardBitmapCache =
        new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY / 2, 0.75f, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(LinkedHashMap.Entry<String, Bitmap> eldest) {
            if (size() > HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY) {
                // Entries push-out of hard reference cache are transferred to soft reference cache
                sSoftBitmapCache.put(eldest.getKey(), new SoftReference<Bitmap>(eldest.getValue()));
                return true;
            } else
                return false;
        }
    };

    // Soft cache for bitmaps kicked out of hard cache
    private final static ConcurrentHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> sSoftBitmapCache =
        new ConcurrentHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>(HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY / 2);

    private final Handler purgeHandler = new Handler();

    private final Runnable purger = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            clearCache();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Adds this bitmap to the cache.
     * @param bitmap The newly downloaded bitmap.
     */
    private void addBitmapToCache(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            synchronized (sHardBitmapCache) {
                sHardBitmapCache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param url The URL of the image that will be retrieved from the cache.
     * @return The cached bitmap or null if it was not found.
     */
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromCache(String url) {
        // First try the hard reference cache
        synchronized (sHardBitmapCache) {
            final Bitmap bitmap = sHardBitmapCache.get(url);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                // Bitmap found in hard cache
                // Move element to first position, so that it is removed last
                sHardBitmapCache.remove(url);
                sHardBitmapCache.put(url, bitmap);
                return bitmap;
            }
        }

        // Then try the soft reference cache
        SoftReference<Bitmap> bitmapReference = sSoftBitmapCache.get(url);
        if (bitmapReference != null) {
            final Bitmap bitmap = bitmapReference.get();
            if (bitmap != null) {
                // Bitmap found in soft cache
                return bitmap;
            } else {
                // Soft reference has been Garbage Collected
                sSoftBitmapCache.remove(url);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Clears the image cache used internally to improve performance. Note that for memory
     * efficiency reasons, the cache will automatically be cleared after a certain inactivity delay.
     */
    public void clearCache() {
        sHardBitmapCache.clear();
        sSoftBitmapCache.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Allow a new delay before the automatic cache clear is done.
     */
    private void resetPurgeTimer() {
        purgeHandler.removeCallbacks(purger);
        purgeHandler.postDelayed(purger, DELAY_BEFORE_PURGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of projects on GitHub
[Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)
[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
[Android Image Manager](https://github.com/felipecsl/Android-ImageManager)
[Android Image Worker](https://github.com/steelkiwi/Android-Image-Worker-Library) (this one is my own "bicycle", more for fun not for production use)

**UPD**

Facebook has recently released their own solution - [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco). Didn't tried, but looks promising.

Comment: Used Picasso, awesome library.. Easy to use. One more help, do you know how to make the image , a rounded one? with picasso

Comment: @John Sorry, I just made a quick look to it. Maybe you can use a solution from Romain Guy http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

Comment: Picasso is awesome, unfortunately libraries like Cordova included a very old version of Picasso's support libs and rendered it useless.

Answer (score 5):

*Hi i hope this will help. This working for me.*

```
public class ImageLoader {

private MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
private FileCache fileCache = null;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
        .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;

private static ImageLoader instance = null;

private ImageLoader() {

}

private ImageLoader(Context context) {

    fileCache = new FileCache(context);

    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

public static ImageLoader getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new ImageLoader(context);
    return instance;
}

public static void setInstance(ImageLoader instance) {
    ImageLoader.instance = instance;
}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.no_img;

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    // from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    // from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

// Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
    String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

// Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
        bitmap = b;
        photoToLoad = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if (bitmap != null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}}
```

*MemoryCache.java*

```
public class MemoryCache {
private Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>());

public Bitmap get(String id){
    if(!cache.containsKey(id))
        return null;
    SoftReference<Bitmap> ref=cache.get(id);
    return ref.get();
}

public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
    cache.put(id, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
}

public void clear() {
    cache.clear();
}}
```

*Utils,java*

```
public class Utils {
public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
{
    final int buffer_size=1024;
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
        for(;;)
        {
          int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
          if(count==-1)
              break;
          os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}}
```

*Now Implement Imageloader like this in you Activity or Adapter.*

```
 private ImageLoader imageLoader = null;
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(context);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(details.url_1, image);
```

Comment: for file cache: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-images-from-web-and-caching/